# Why does Python3 exec() raise an AttributeError when a variable is not in locals but is in gl

Tags: python, dictionary, exec, locals

When I pass a bona fide dict for `locals`, `exec()` does the correct thing and falls back to the globals dictionary for missing names.  However, if I pass a LazyMap (dict-like object) as locals, accesses to globals raise an AttributeError from inside the lambda given to LazyMap.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class LazyMap:
    def __init__(self, keys, getter):
        self._keys = keys
        self._getter = getter

    def keys(self):
        return self._keys

    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return self._getter(k)

class TestObj:
    def __init__(self):
        self.field = 'foo'

obj = TestObj()

# this prints 'foo'
locs = dict((name, getattr(obj, name)) for name in dir(obj))
exec('print(field)', globals(), locs)

# this raises AttributeError
locs = LazyMap(dir(obj), lambda k,s=obj: getattr(s, k))
exec('print(field)', globals(), locs)
```

Why is an exception raised with LazyMap but not with a plain dict?  How can I create a locals map that will only fetch/compute the value if accessed from the exec?

Comment: Why are you using `globals()`, `exec()`, and ostensibly `locals()` (although I don't see that one) to do whatever it is you're trying to achieve? What exactly are you trying to achieve, anyway?

Comment: I'm creating a text interface programmable with simple Python one-liners.  For example, `d`elete is `rows.pop(cursorRowIndex)`, where both `rows` and `cursorRowIndex` are attributes of the shown object.  The problem is that some attributes are computed, and might either be invalid or take a long time to compute.  There are dozens of attributes available, but it's not necessary (and will even be problematic) to compute them all just for the handful that are used for the current command.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that exec() first tries to getitem on the locals object, and if a `KeyError` is raised, it then falls back to getitem on the globals object.  However, in the given code, `getattr` will raise an AttributeError instead of a KeyError.  Changing the passed lambda to `vars(s)[k]` will cause a missing key to raise the correct KeyError instead.

To summarize: `__getitem__` should raise `KeyError` on missing key, while `__getattr__` should raise `AttributeError`.